# Indexed Table View for Facebook Friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to sort my Facebook friends list in order to implement an indexed table view, exactly like the one found in Facebook Messenger.

I originally tried to use the `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` but I am stuck on the "`collationStringSelector`" because my dataSource array are `id<"FBGraphUser">` objects and therefore have no properties I can use for the selector. Any ideas of how to implement this (it does not have to be using this method, I am open to anything!)?

```
-(NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector {
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];

    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count]; // section count is take from sectionTitles and not sectionIndexTitles
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

    // create an array to hold the data for each section
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
        [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    // put each object into a section
    for (id object in array) {
        NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:object collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

    // sort each section
    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
        [sections addObject:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:selector]];
    }

    return sections;
}
```

Comment: FBGraphUser has lots of properties like first_name, last_name, location, etc. You should be able to use any of these for sorting.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how I may be able to sort it properly into the collation? I am going to sort by last_name

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subclass of UITableViewController that I created some time ago to make an indexed table view. I use this as a base class for the controller whose table view appears on screen, so it's intended to be a reusable class that does the hard work of creating the table. You might be able to use it as is, but I didn't try to make it too universal. I pass in a simple array of custom objects (my objects just had first and last names), and this class creates the sections and the index. So here's the code,

the .h

```
@interface RDIndexedTableController : UITableViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *inputArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *sectionKey;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *secondarySortKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation;

-(void)convertArray:(NSArray *)input usingSectionKey:(NSString *)key secondarySortKey:(NSString *)sorter;
@end
```

The .m

```
@interface RDIndexedTableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *firstLetterArray;
@end

@implementation RDIndexedTableController


-(void)convertArray:(NSArray *)input usingSectionKey:(NSString *)key secondarySortKey:(NSString *)sorter {
    self.inputArray = input;
    self.sectionKey = key;
    self.secondarySortKey = sorter;
    [self configureSections];
}


- (void)configureSections {

    self.collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionTitlesCount = [[self.collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *newSectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitlesCount];

    for (int index = 0; index < sectionTitlesCount; index++) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [newSectionsArray addObject:array];
    }

    for (id obj in self.inputArray) {
        NSInteger sectionNumber = [self.collation.sectionTitles indexOfObject:[[obj valueForKey:self.sectionKey] substringToIndex:1]];

        NSMutableArray *sectionForObjects = [newSectionsArray objectAtIndex:sectionNumber];
        [sectionForObjects addObject:obj];
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < sectionTitlesCount; index++) {

        NSMutableArray *objectArrayForSection = [newSectionsArray objectAtIndex:index];
        NSArray *firstSortedObjectArrayForSection = [self.collation sortedArrayFromArray:objectArrayForSection collationStringSelector:NSSelectorFromString(self.secondarySortKey)];
        NSArray *sortedObjectArrayForSection = [self.collation sortedArrayFromArray:firstSortedObjectArrayForSection collationStringSelector:NSSelectorFromString(self.sectionKey)];
        [newSectionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:sortedObjectArrayForSection];
    }
    self.sectionsArray = newSectionsArray;
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.collation.sectionTitles.count;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *objectsInSection = [self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return objectsInSection.count;
}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.collation.sectionTitles[section];
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] count] == 0) {
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 30;
    }
}



- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return @[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z"];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.collation sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

In the table view controller that appears in the app, I only need this small amount of code to populate the table,

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    NSMutableArray *mut = [NSMutableArray new];
    // create the Person objects and add them to the array here

    [self convertArray:mut usingSectionKey:@"lastName" secondarySortKey:@"firstName"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *first = [self.sectionsArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"firstName"];
    NSString *last = [self.sectionsArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lastName"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",first,last];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will definitely read through your solution and see if I can adapt it for my own use!